# Create new column which checks other columns before inserting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-manipulation

I have a  df and I want to insert a new column which checks ColA, ColB, and ColC. The new column will have value 'Yes' unless any of those have corresponding values for the Cols above are met( provided in the dictionary). How do I achieve this in python?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

to_check= {'ColA':'Yes', 'ColB':'Y','ColC':'True'}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
            'ID': ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB03', 'AB04', 'AB05','AB06','AB07','AB08'],
            'ColA': ["Yes","No",np.nan,"No",
                     "Yes", "","", "No"],
            'ColB': ["N","","Y","",
                     "Y", np.nan,"", "N"],
            'ColC': [np.nan,"True","False",np.nan,"False",
                     "True", "",""],
            'Type': [85,98,84,70,50,np.nan,85,74] 
    }
)
```

The end result should be like this with new column named 'Result' and I have to use the dictionary in the code:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use if not `any` of the rows match the dictionary value:

```
c = df[to_check.keys()].eq(to_check).any(1)
df['Result'] = np.where(c,'','Yes')
```

---

```
print(df)

     ID ColA ColB   ColC  Type Result
0  AB01  Yes    N    NaN  85.0       
1  AB02   No        True  98.0       
2  AB03  NaN    Y  False  84.0       
3  AB04   No         NaN  70.0    Yes
4  AB05  Yes    Y  False  50.0       
5  AB06       NaN   True   NaN       
6  AB07                   85.0    Yes
7  AB08   No    N         74.0    Yes
```